# CoffeeScript2: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: express, import, syntax, coffeescript, babeljs

I'm working on a express server. I can develop faster using CoffeeScript2 ("write less do more").
The code

```
import { Sequelize, Model, DataTypes } from 'sequelize'
```

gives me the error:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I guess I have to use babel? How can I set it up?